# Do sockets created in C work over a network?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to create a very simple chat service as an exercise using sockets in C.

The client, upon input of a message from the user, directs it to a server which then writes it into a file. The client reads this file every few milliseconds, and displays the contents on to the terminal window (after clearing it, of course).

My question is: will this work over different computers connected to the same network? I don't have access to another computer right now, so I can't check for myself.

My service should work on the same computer, theoretically, but I really want it to work on different computers at the same time (only on the same network). Only one of them will run the server, the remaining connect to it (using a pre-defined port).
I haven't started coding it as of now, just so you guys know.

Is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible -- that is the whole idea behind sockets. Make sure to separate the code processing input from the communication, and make sure that the (separated) communication just uses file descriptors. Then you can use anything that gives you a file descriptor -- i.e.stdin/out via console, local sockets, files, network sockets -- as communication partners. That's the sweet thing in *nix/*six.

Comment: "*... to a server, who then writes it into a file. The client reads this file ...*" the server writes a file, which then is read by the client? How would the client access this file, if the server runs on a differnt machine as the client?

Comment: @alk you are right, the idea to monitor a file for changes is a typical pre-network IPC ;-). OP, you don't want to do that. Write it back to the client through the same (or another) socket, whether client and server are on the same machine or not.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: What is "*pre-network IPC*", carrying around diskettes? ;-)? And how would I access a file on another server without a network? "*... you don't want to do that.*" S/he simply can't if using different machines.

Comment: @alk: If you do not have dedicated inter process communication you can monitor files for changes and communicate through them. Been there, done that. Obviously that only works on the same machine, or on a shared drive -- but then one has a network, of some kind :-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider So you mean I'd have to maintain separate files for each client? Whenever a new message arrives, I write to all connected clients?
That seems possible, if I accompany a recvfrom() after every sendto() call, right?

Comment: Most likely, no files at all, unless you need to buffer large amounts of data. The client would not display a file contents but a message it received back from the server.

Comment: I still do **not** understand this sentence "*The client reads this file every ...*". How will the client be able to read what is on the server, assuming differnet machines? The OP might like to clarify this?

Comment: @alk The server should send it back through the socket, of course. What you pointed out is entirely correct and just rooted in the OP's attempt to design a trivial first networking program, I believe. No files are necessary, and for a remote server, no files are possible.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Ok, although someone might consider this nitpicking: Then the client does not read the file but from a/the socket. Reading the file is done by the server.

Comment: Even if this approach would work, clearing the screen and writing the entire chat history to the terminal every few milliseconds seems like a fantastically inefficient approach.

Comment: Yes, they do...................

Comment: @alk I think I might not have been clear. What I meant initially was, I would maintain a single file to store all the chat messages. Then when a client requests, the server would send back the contents of the file.
As others pointed out, it might be better to maintain a file at the client side.

However, I think if I fork a new process from the server every time a new client joins, I don't think I'll need a file at all. All this is theoretical, so it'll be better if I start coding and let you all know how it turns out. Thanks a lot everyone! You all helped!

Comment: Don't forget if you `fork()` a new server process for each client, you're going to have to find some way to communicate the chat messages received by one to all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Making two local processes to communicate with each other is the step in the right direction.

Generally, the code shall work without modifications, if you watch accurately which network addresses you are using.

For example, if you use 127.0.0.1, than everything would work on your local PC, but not through network. Such issues relate to network routing protocols, and your local network configuration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. If I understood correctly, the IP address of the local server should work instead of 127.0.0.1 right?

Comment: @llsiddhantll this applies to server as well: you can bind it to local interface,  to public network, or to both. For example, when your server listens on loopback (127.0.0.1) you would not be able to connect to it from network.